# phonegap malfomed config.xml

Tags: adobe, phonegap

Whenever I upload my **`phonegap app`** to the **`adobe phonegap`** build I get a banner that says my **config.xml** is malformed...

What do I have to do to fix that?

```
<?xml version="0.0.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget id="tk.dubafly.budle" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

<name>Budle</name>
    <description>
        Budle is a Crypto-Currency Investment
        simulation aimed to help those who are
        looking into bitcoin investment...

        Bitcoins are seen as a mythical 
        bridge between nerdiness and lucrative
        success, allowing for the speculation 
        of a necessary intellect, but thats not
        quite true...

        Though bitcoin investment can be tricky 
        upon starting, with the help of this 
        mobile application, the knowledge and 
        path to crypto-success are rather clear.
    </description>

    <author email="elithedev@gmail.com" href="http://dubafly.tk">
        Appalanche
    </author>

    <icon src="img/budleIcon.png" />

</widget>
```

Comment: For some reason it cut out the widget and header...

Comment: <?xml version="0.0.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget id="tk.dubafly.budle" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">